# How to add an orange line under the imageView image programatically?

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams

How do i add an orange line under the image before it's showed in the gallery?
I want to mark the picture so it sticks out from all the other.

I have tested all kinds of LayoutParams but need advice.
See loots of explanations how to do this in the xml only.
here is my `getView` in the adapter

(UPDATE WITH WORKING SOLUTION IF ANYONE NEED IT)
The `imageViewWithLine` is the custom imageView that has a boolean
to determent if line should be drawn or not

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){

       BitmapFactory.Options bf = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       bf.inSampleSize = 8; 
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files.get(position).getImagePath(),bf);
       ImageViewWithLine imageViewWithLine = new ImageViewWithLine(ctx, null);
       BitmapDrawable b = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
       imageViewWithLine.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
       imageViewWithLine.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
       imageViewWithLine.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
       imageViewWithLine.setBackgroundDrawable(b);
       convertView = imageViewWithLine;

    }

    if(files.get(position).addLine() == true){
       ((ImageViewWithLine)convertView).setLine(true);
    }else
    ((ImageViewWithLine)convertView).setLine(false);

    return convertView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the ImageView class and create a custom view.  In the custom view you can override the onDraw and draw your orange line that way.

**Update:**

This is just a normal button, with an orange bar along the bottom of it.  The dimensions aren't exact, but it should give you a good starting point.

```
public class ButtonWithLine extends Button {

    public ButtonWithLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 125, 0));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        canvas.drawRect(0, getHeight() - height, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working but i must scroll the gallery out-of-view and back again to get the line to show. If i have 100 images in the gallery it's not efficient to redrawe all just to get one  image-line to show. Is there a way to tell gallery to reload only on image or something

Comment: I updated my question,  love to see a solution how to make gallery update selected view only

Comment: got it working now by calling invalidate() on the custom imageview.
Thanks @zeonic